# How can I detect if text is paste using right-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I paste text using ctrl c and ctrl v on table1(For example on "Apple"), duplicate text on input on table2 still change, but If i paste using right click and paste,duplicate input on table 2 does NOT change. :( Ive created two different event(keyup and change) but nothing seems to work when text is paste using right click. Please see below :

[Keypress fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L7bnzrz0/11/)

```
$(document).off('keydown').on('keydown', $('#table1 tbody tr td input:eq(0)'), function (e) {
var oldValue =$(e.target).val();//get the input value before keypress or edit
    $(document).on('keyup', $('#table1 tbody tr td input'),function(e){ 
        $('#table2').find('td input').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() === oldValue){
                $(this).val($(e.target).val());
            }
        $(document).off('keyup');
        });
    });              
});
```

[on change fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6aej3Lf/1/)

```
var oldValue;
$(document).on('keydown', '.main', function (e) {
    oldValue = $(this).val();
    foo(oldValue);
});
var newValue;
$(document).on('keyup', '.main', function (e) {
    newValue = $(this).val();
    foo(oldValue);
});
function foo(oldValue) {
    $('#table1').find('tbody tr').find('td input').change(function (i) {
        var orig = $(this).val();

        $('#table2 tbody tr').find('td input').each(function (i) {
            if (oldValue == $(this).val()) {
                $(this).val(orig);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: in modern browsers can use `input` event to capture `paste` and key events

Comment: @charlietfl at the moment support for `InputEvent` seems low for many of the features. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @BernardV that is a special interface . See https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event

Comment: @charlietfl I see, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the characters onChange (since you can only enter one character at a time.

**Edit:**

Why it wasn't working:

on your jsfiddle remember to set `onDomReady`  in the frameworks & extension for the equivalent of `$(document).ready(handlerFn)`

When you use `on('change', handlerFn)` or `.change(handlerFn)` on an input it will fire only after the textbox loses focus ( `blur` ). The response is not instantaneous like when you use `select` on your forms. Use `bind("input", handlerFn)` instead of `on(change)` for inputs.

The code below will update the matching word on #table2 from the one being edited on #table1. Updating will work for copy-paste CTRL C/V or on mouse copy/paste events. It will also alert if the user copy/paste by comparing the length of the old and new value.

```
$("#table1 >* input").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this),
    oldValue;

    elem.on('focus', function () {
        elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
        elem.data('oldLen', elem.data('oldVal').length);
    });

    // Look for changes in the value, 
    // bind 'input' event to the textbox to fire the function
    // every time the input changes (paste, delete, type etc.)
    elem.bind("input", function(event){
        oldValue = elem.data('oldVal');
        // update oldVal
        elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
        // check if pasted
        if (elem.val().length - elem.data('oldLen') > 1 ) {
            alert('Most certainly pasted');
        }
        // update input value length
        elem.data('oldLen', elem.data('oldVal').length);

        // update #table2
       foo(oldValue, elem.val()) ;
    });
});
```

And the function to update #table2

```
function foo(oldValue, newValue) {
    $('#table2')
      .find('input')
      .each(function (i) {
          if (oldValue === $(this).val()) {
              $(this).val(newValue);
          }
      });
}
```

here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfabfab/u6aej3Lf/5/) for you to play with

Comment: it is update [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfabfab/u6aej3Lf/5/) for you to play with. I have also posted an answer with a few tips

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.Can you check my another question here regarding If input is from another dialog window and input is programatically updated

Comment: What do you mean by another dialog window? do you mean whether or not the input is from table 1 or 2 ? I don't follow.... please clarify. better yet, if it is from another code, create another question ;)

Comment: see this @jfab fab http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422338/document-onfocus-or-document-bindinput-not-trigger-on-dynamically-a

Answer (score 1):

Check this code, Hope this will help you:

```
jQuery('#some_text_box').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    var text1 = $('#some_text_box').val();
    //alert(text1);

    $('#tab2').val(text1);

});
```

This is your first text box `#some_text_box`.

```
<input type='text' value = "Apple" id='some_text_box' />
```

And this is table 2 text box `#tab2`

```
<input type='text' value="Apple" id='tab2'/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/np07seby/1/)

Comment: hi,whats the difference of jQuery and this $? i tried to change it to $('#some_text_box') and it perfectly works the same.

Comment: don't bother about that. $ and jQuery both point to the window.jQuery object, so they are one and the same. the reason some scripts use jQuery instead of $ is to prevent conflicts with other libraries such as prototype or different versions of jquery which both also use the $ variable.

Comment: This help me to detect paste event using right click,but my code for getting the input value before keyup and down is ruined.See this http://jsfiddle.net/u6aej3Lf/2/

Comment: I didn't get it. What you mean by 'before keyup and down'

Comment: for example, I want to get the value of the input(first table) before it was edited, so I can compare it to the values on the second table, and If i found a match,I will change it to the current(input value when already edited) input value(first table)

Answer (score 0):

Ok well this will detect for you if the user uses Ctrl + V etc but thats it. If they right click and paste then you will need another expression to capture that. I left this open by using `keydown`and `keyup`so you can capture more variations if needed.

This is jQuery so you will need the library to cover this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ctrlDown = false;
    var ctrlKey = 17, vKey = 86, cKey = 67;

    $(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = true;
    }).keyup(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = false;
    });

    $("#no-copy-paste").keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == vKey || e.keyCode == cKey)) return false;
    });
});
```

Here is an article on handlers that may be some help to you as well.
http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

-Epik