# $(document).on('focus' or $(document).bind('input', not trigger on dynamically added row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `$(document).on('focus' or $(document).bind('input','input:text'` so my method for automatically change duplicate input values from table1 to table2 via(keypress), but my code does not trigger,If the user will change the input (from new row) that was added to table dynamically.

This happen,for instance, click the Add row button,Edit the new "Apple" field and see that this will not change the duplicate "Apple" on table2.

See this for [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eq8qvLnn/7/) for demo.

```
$("input:text").each(function () {
    var elem = $(this),
        oldValue;
       $('input:text').trigger('focus');
    $(document).on('focus', 'input:text', function () {
        elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
        elem.data('oldLen', elem.data('oldVal').length);
    });
    $(document).bind('input', 'input:text', function (event) {
        oldValue = elem.data('oldVal');
        elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
        if (elem.val().length - elem.data('oldLen') > 1) {
            alert('Most certainly pasted');
        }
        elem.data('oldLen', elem.data('oldVal').length);
       foo(oldValue,elem.val());
    });
});
$("input").blur();
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two things you say you used?

Comment: I used the `focus` so I can still get the input values before it was edited and the `input` is to detect events like keypress or paste. Actually,I believe this event fires,because I used to add logs or alert inside that event but my code to automatically update the duplicate on table 2 is not triggers.

Comment: The first line of the question says _I used $(document).on('focus', 'input:text', and $(document).on('focus'', 'input:text'_. What is the difference between those two things?

Comment: Both of the events are `focus`, they both use `on`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

`.bind()` doesn't take a selector argument, only `.on()` does. If you're binding to dynamically-added elements, you need to use `.on()`.

```
$(document).on('input', 'input:text', function ...);
```

[Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/eq8qvLnn/12/)

The other problem is that you're using `$("input:text").each()`. That will only process the elements that existed when the page was loaded. You don't need that loop, just bind your event handlers normally. You don't need the variables `elem` and `oldValue` outside handlers; within the handler, `$(this)` is the element that the event was triggered on, and you can get `oldValue` from `.data()`.

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input:text', function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
    elem.data('oldLen', elem.data('oldVal').length);
});

$(document).on('input', 'input:text', function (event) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var oldValue = elem.data('oldVal') || '';
    elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
    if (elem.val().length - oldValue.length > 1) {
        alert('Most certainly pasted');
    }
    elem.data('oldLen', elem.data('oldVal').length);
    foo(oldValue, elem.val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks. see my reply on your question above :)

Comment: I don't understand that answer, I think you didn't understand my question.

Comment: Sorry on that, but I already stated,why I used that two events.

Comment: I didn't ask why you use two events. Your question only has one event, they both say `focus`.

Comment: Whatda, Its a typo eror sir. I mean also this `$(document).on('focus' or $(document).bind('input',`, Anyways I try to change `bind` to `on` but still my table2 does not change. see this http://jsfiddle.net/eq8qvLnn/9/

Comment: I see your corrected Fiddle, but my issue is still there, If I click the `add Row button`, then edit the "Apple" on the newly add row also. Duplicates "Apple"'s in table2 are not automatically change.

Comment: `elem` and `oldValue` are set during the `.each()` loop, so they'll only be set for elements that were on the page when the document was loaded.

Comment: I already thought of that, but I dont see examples that use $(document).each ,some post at this site are not so related to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have refactored your code. **Note : ** You should not have a static id when adding elements dynamically. Ids are supposed to be unique and as it is, your inputs will all have the same id `input_0`.
Instead, since you have only one input per row, get the index of the row to create ids dynamically (input0, input1,..., inputN). See the code below, it's commented.

Another thing, your table2 was not updated because you are adding rows dynamically and the $(selector).each() is only running once. if you put it inside a function to be invoked every time a row is added everything will work fine.

```
//----------adding a row
$(document).on("click", '.tdAdd', function () {
    var table = $(this).parents("#table1");

    // get the row
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

    // get the current value of the input
    // in order to duplicate it
    var currentVal = currentRow.children().find("input[type='text']").val();

    // one way to create a cell
    var buttonCell = '<td><input type="button" value="Add Row" class="tdAdd"/></td>';

    // but I'd rather do it like this
    // because I can assign any value as an attribute - dynamic
    var inputCell = $("<td>").append($('<input type="text"/>').attr({
           id : "input" + (currentRow.index() + 1),
           value : currentVal,
           class : "ttt"
        }));

    table.append(
        $("<tr>").append(buttonCell, inputCell)
    );

    // invoking this function in order to update $(selector).each()
    updateEachFn();
});
```

and the wrapper function

```
// wrap $(selector).each() inside a function to be invoked 
// every time a row is added to keep everything up to date
function updateEachFn() {

  $("input:text").each(function () {

    var elem = $(this),
        oldValue;

    $('input:text').trigger('focus');

    // do not use document, because it will unnecessarily go through
    // every single input -- bad for performance
    // also you are already on an input:text ie each() above
    elem.bind('focus', function () {
        elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
        elem.data('oldLen', elem.data('oldVal').length);
    });
    elem.bind('input', function (event) {

        oldValue = elem.data('oldVal');
        elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
        if (elem.val().length - elem.data('oldLen') > 1) {
            alert('Most certainly pasted');
        }
        elem.data('oldLen', elem.data('oldVal').length);
       foo(oldValue,elem.val());
    });
  });
}
$("input").blur(); 

// invoke it once for input0
updateEachFn();
```

here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfabfab/eq8qvLnn/18/) for you to play with

Comment: Thanks @jfab jfab , but i used this `$('input:text').trigger('focus'); ` so that if I click the button(@ the right of the input),I still get the data that was clicked on pop up table(A1 or B1).

Comment: ok! in thath case just uncomment it and all will work fine ( I already edited the post and jsfiddle)